# why is DataOutputStream any different than FileWriter when you can use scanners?

Tags: java

I know DataOutput stream can write java primitives. But
when reading a file written by fileWriter you can use a java scanner to achieve the same thing, right?

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new FileReader("writtenByFileWriter.txt"));
scanner.nextInt() //if we want to read an integer
scanner.nextDouble() //if we want to read a double
```

Comment: `Scanner` = input, `*Writer` = output.  What are you saying?

Comment: Your question confuses me. Writers are used for text and text only. Data streams are usually used for non-textual data output, and as noted above, Scanner is for text input. You might benefit from reading a tutorial on Java i/o

Answer (score 1):

> I know DataOutput stream can write java primitives.

Yes.

> But when reading a file written by `FileWriter` you can use a `Scanner` to achieve the same thing, right?

You can read a file written using `FileWriter` using a `Scanner`.  Any `Writer` writes text, and a `Scanner` reads text.

But generally speaking you *can't* read a file written using `DataOutputStream` by using a `Scanner`.  If you try, you will get garbage / exceptions.  That is because `DataOutputStream` is writing primitives (for example) in binary form.

You should typically use a `DataInputStream` to read data written using a `DataOutputStream`.